# Implementing webrtc at server side

Tags: javascript, html5-video, webrtc

Is it possible to implement webRTC at server side? ie., I want my browser to connect to a http server(tomcat which runs a java based app to stream a video) using webRTC protocol and get the streem from the server?

I think compiling webRTC api and access it through JNI will help. Any other easy directions to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is now a server-side implementation of WebRTC in Asterisk that should enable that: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+WebRTC+Support

I haven't yet looked into it that much so I can't say for sure that it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Lynckia's Licode Project](http://lynckia.com/licode/index.html). It is however, Node.js serverside.